# C++: The strange behavior when initialize member data

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, memory-management

I've encountered a strange behavior about `C++17 static inline member data`.
There is `Implementation` abstract class:

```
class Implementation
{
public:
  virtual void call() = 0;
};
```

There are `Example` and `AnotherExample` classes that implement the abstract class:

```
class Example : public Implementation
{
public:
  void call() override
  {
    cout << "Called Example::call function!" << endl;
  }
};

class AnotherExample : public Implementation
{
public:
  void call() override
  {
    cout << "Called AnotherExample::call function!" << endl;
  }
};
```

Finally there is `Implementer` class to use `Example` and `AnotherExample` classes:

```
class Implementer
{
private:
  static inline Implementation* example = unique_ptr<Example>(new Example).get(); // or make_unique<Example>().get()
  static inline Implementation* another_example = new AnotherExample;
public:
  static Implementation* get_example(bool flag)
  {
    // This function returns example object if flag is true otherwise another_example object.
    if (flag)
      return example;
    else
      return another_example;
  }
};
```

Using:

```
Implementer::get_example(true)->call(); // This expect to return example.
Implementer::get_example(false)->call(); // This expect to return another_example.
```

We expect to see this:

```
Called Example::call function!
Called AnotherExample::call function!
```

but we see this:

```
Called AnotherExample::call function!
Called AnotherExample::call function!
```

I don't understand it. How does `example` object get the value of `another_example` object?

**Edit:** We can get desired output if we change

```
static inline Implementation* example = unique_ptr<Example>(new Example).get();
```

to

```
static inline unique_ptr<Implementation> example = unique_ptr<Example>(new Example);
```

Comment: The problem is actually not related at all to static initialization or members; the exact same thing would happen with regular members, or indeed any expression which creates a temporary unique_ptr and later accesses the pointer. (It actually resembles much older, identical issues with std::string::c_str()). Can you fix the title and tags? I could do it but I feel it is too intrusive if I simply "take control".

Answer (score 5):

The `unique_ptr<Example>(new Example).get()` would destroy the new `Example` instance as soon as the result of `get()` gets assigned (thanks @JVApen for correcting).

From that point on a whole lot of strange things may happen.

For instance, the object allocated by `new AnotherExample` can (and most probably will) be placed to the same memory where the first one was, and the first pointer would suddenly point to a valid live object again.

Not sure if this qualifies as an [ABA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem) phenomenon, but what happens is very similar -- you think you are looking at A, but it's a different A.

I'd first clean it up under [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) or [ASAN](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html).

Coliru sandbox [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dc9e46884444234)

Comment: Actually, when get returns the value is still valid. It's only at the sequence point (read ; ) that temporaries go out of scope. So the assignment will first happen, than the unique_ptr goes out of scope.

Comment: @bobah Why does `unique_ptr<ABC>(new ABC).get()` not destroy `new ABC` instance? The code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c7317d0cccb0df8

Comment: It does, but memory is still not corrupted or returned to the OS, so the process does not get killed. I [added debug print from destructor in your example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eda7a6f60c45ec47).

Comment: Actually I ask why does the memory is corrupted if `ABC` class implements inheritance `Abstract` class (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9be9afed370095cc) but the memory is still not corrupted if `ABC` class doesn't implement inheritance `Absctract` class (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0b44945f263d0c4)? If you check codes we see `Called ABC::call function!` message but don't see same message another code.

Comment: It may be an expensive research. With C/C++ you would normally just assume that if a program is not correct or the behavior is "undefined", then _anything_ can happen. A finger-in-the-air guess is that a class with virtual table is larger and is triggering some memory recycling mechanism which a more basic class isn't.